# Evaluating the integral of a complex valued function of a real variable.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to find $$ \int_0^{+\infty }e^{-zt} dt,$$ where $\Re(z) >0$. 
The integration comes to $$[-z e^{-zt}]$$ then on applying limits , I found the final answer to be $z$. 
But the derrivative of $z$ comes to be $0$. I am not getting if my answer is right or not.

Comment: Your antiderivative is wrong.

Comment: What is the antiderrivative then?

Comment: The first step you took was slightly wrong in finding the antiderivative of $e^{-zt}$


$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-zt} dt = [\frac{e^{-zt}}{-z}]_{0}^{+\infty}$